# Merge columns with the same name R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R.  I'm working with a data set that is incredibly redundant with a lot of columns (~400).  There are several duplicate column names, however the data is not duplicate, so I need to sum the columns when collapsing them.

The columns all have a similar name that allows easy identification, so I'm hoping I can use that to my advantage.

I attempted to perform the following:

```
ColNames <- unique(colnames(df))
CombinedDf <- data.frame(sapply(ColNames, function(i)rowSums(Test[,ColNames==i, drop=FALSE])))
```

This works if I sum over the range of columns that only contain integers, but the issue is that other columns have strings and such in them, so rowSums throws a fit.

Assuming that the identifier is "XXX", how can I aggregate all the columns that are of the same name leaving the other columns as is?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: Sample data has been asked for, I cannot give the exact data as it is sensitive, but I will give an example:

```
Name    COL1XXX    COL2XXX    COL1XXX    COL3XXX    COL2XXX   Type
Henry   5          15         25         31         1         Orange
Tom     8          16         12         4          3         Green
```

Should return

```
Name    COL1XXX   COL2XXX   COL3XXX    Type
Henry   30        16        31         Orange
Tom     20        19        4          Green
```

Comment: Did you say the names are the same or just similar? By the way, it's strongly preferred to provide example data so that we can validate our answers for you with it (just for future reference).

Comment: `colsWeWant <- colnames(df)[ grepl( "XXX", colnames(df) ) ]`

Comment: right but wouldn't the first step be splitting by which one are numeric or "XXX", then applying the row sum then combining back as one new column to original minus the inital subset? I know it might be a little long but it should work

Comment: @NathanDay Oh ok, I just thought you were suggesting that as a complete answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure, but you may try transposing the data and then aggregating by unique names.

```
t_df=as.data.frame(t(df))

new_df=aggregate(t_df, by=list(rownames(t_df)),sum)
```

Again, without sample data I'm unsure if it'll work, but based on what you said, that might work.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try as soon as I am able.  The data is sensitive and therefore I cannot list it here.  I will put an example in my original question.